# How to combine this list/dict in one dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I am new to python and pandas dataframe, I have this list/dict output and I need to combine it in one dataframe. I'm having trouble combining it in one dataframe and saving it in one csv.

```
data = [{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST1","A":"0.30001","B":"0.0002","C":"0.00003","D":"0.000047","D":"0.0003","E":"0.00006"}][{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST2","C":"0.700003","D":"00001","D":"00005","E":"00005","F":"0.000008","G":"000.245","H":"1.111258","I":"0000.1236"}]
```

Comment: This won't solve the issue but you are missing a double quote around D

Comment: @SimonT ooops sorry my bad, already edit it.

Comment: can you try: `df=pd.json_normalize(your_list_dict_output)[0].apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: That variable isn't valid, you can't have two lists assigned to a variable without it being an iterable.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    {
        "TimePeriod_Start": "2022-10-01",
        "TimePeriod_End": "2022-10-02",
        "PLATFORM": "TEST1",
        "A": "0.30001",
        "B": "0.0002",
        "C": "0.00003",
        "D": "0.0003",
        "E": "0.00006",
    }
]
data2 = [
    {
        "TimePeriod_Start": "2022-10-01",
        "TimePeriod_End": "2022-10-02",
        "PLATFORM": "TEST2",
        "C": "0.700003",
        "D": "00005",
        "E": "00005",
        "F": "0.000008",
        "G": "000.245",
        "H": "1.111258",
        "I": "0000.1236",
    }
]

d = data+data2
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d).to_csv("filePath")
```

Or simply

```
pd.DataFrame(data + data2)
```

**UPDATE FOR NEW INFO**

Since the data is being returned as an iterable already you can either flatten the data to create a dataFrame for it with the original iterable (This is not recommened as it means you create a new list which requires memory.

Or use the nice built in feature of pandas to normalize the JSON (**This would be preferred**)

This negates the need of the for loop, which I can only assume you used to print the nested data for visualisation.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST1","A":"0.30001","B":"0.0002","C":"0.00003","D":"0.000047","D":"0.0003","E":"0.00006"}],[{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST2","C":"0.700003","D":"00001","D":"00005","E":"00005","F":"0.000008","G":"000.245","H":"1.111258","I":"0000.1236"}]]

flat_data = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame(flat_data)
```

**Preferred method**

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)[0].apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: the problem is, with my scenario the output comes from one variable only 
data = [{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST1","A":"0.30001","B":"0.0002","C":"0.00003","D":"0.000047","D":"0.0003","E":"0.00006"}]
[{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST2","C":"0.700003","D":"00001","D":"00005","E":"00005","F":"0.000008","G":"000.245","H":"1.111258","I":"0000.1236"}]

Comment: Could you please update your question to make that clear. When you said you tried to append it makes it seem as if it is two different lists.
Is this output JSON?

Comment: edited the question and I also update the list/dict format. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That variable is not correct python, you can't have 2 lists assigned to a variable like this without it being iterable

Comment: the output comes from a loop that's why there is like two list/dict, just want to combine or merge it if it is possible.

Comment: @jellobeann I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST1","A":"0.30001","B":"0.0002","C":"0.00003","D":"0.000047","D":"0.0003","E":"0.00006"}]
b = [{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST2","C":"0.700003","D":"00001","D":"00005","E":"00005","F":"0.000008","G":"000.245","H":"1.111258","I":"0000.1236"}]
```

I'm not exactly sure you want which dataframe to combine with. Is this what you want?

```
pd.DataFrame(a + b)
```

```
    TimePeriod_Start    TimePeriod_End  PLATFORM    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
0   2022-10-01  2022-10-02  TEST1   0.30001 0.0002  0.00003 0.0003  0.00006 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2022-10-01  2022-10-02  TEST2   NaN NaN 0.700003    00005   00005   0.000008    000.245 1.111258    0000.1236
```

Comment: I just have one variable for the output, something like this|
a = [{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST1","A":"0.30001","B":"0.0002","C":"0.00003","D":"0.000047","D":"0.0003","E":"0.00006"}][{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST2","C":"0.700003","D":"00001","D":"00005","E":"00005","F":"0.000008","G":"000.245","H":"1.111258","I":"0000.1236"}]

Comment: @jellobeann your variable not correct python syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data[0], orient='index').T
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are missing square brackets and comma. True format must be like this:

```
data = [[{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST1","A":"0.30001","B":"0.0002","C":"0.00003","D":"0.000047","D":"0.0003","E":"0.00006"}],[{"TimePeriod_Start":"2022-10-01","TimePeriod_End":"2022-10-02","PLATFORM":"TEST2","C":"0.700003","D":"00001","D":"00005","E":"00005","F":"0.000008","G":"000.245","H":"1.111258","I":"0000.1236"}]]

df = pd.json_normalize(data)[0].apply(pd.Series)
'''
|    | TimePeriod_Start   | TimePeriod_End   | PLATFORM   |         A |        B |        C |      D |     E |       F |       G |         H |        I |
|---:|:-------------------|:-----------------|:-----------|----------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|------:|--------:|--------:|----------:|---------:|
|  0 | 2022-10-01         | 2022-10-02       | TEST1      |   0.30001 |   0.0002 | 3e-05    | 0.0003 | 6e-05 | nan     | nan     | nan       | nan      |
|  1 | 2022-10-01         | 2022-10-02       | TEST2      | nan       | nan      | 0.700003 | 5      | 5     |   8e-06 |   0.245 |   1.11126 |   0.1236 |
'''
```